How to fix global authorization in Blazor breaking CSS?
I added global authorization to a Blazor server application using this code in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

It works well. This also gives me the option disable authorization on a specific page by adding @attribute [AllowAnonymous] to it. I added the attribute to the sign-in page which looks like so:

However, without any errors in the console, the page's styling always breaks if I visit it incognito:

But the moment I sign in, every page's styling works again.
This behavior is leading me to believe that global authorization prevents the app from retrieving styling files, but I don't know how to fix that.
One way of fixing it that worked was to remove global authorization and authorize only the pages that need it. However, I like the global approach better because then during development I don't need to worry about forgetting to authorize a page.
How can I keep global authorization and fix this issue with page styling?

You can ensure that the static file middleware is added before the authorization, like:
app.UseStaticFiles(); 
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

Then, You can try to use middleware to allow anonymous users to access static resources. For example:
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // Allow anonymous access to specific static resources (e.g., CSS and JS)
    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/css") || 
        context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/js") || 
        context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/_content"))
    {
        // Set an anonymous user identity
        context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity();
    }

    await next();
});


Thanks, just adding app.UseStaticFiles fixed the issue. I'm curious why would I need the second part if the first was enough?

Oh, sorry for my unclear statement, you don't need the second part. What I mean is that you can try the first part first, and if it doesn't work, you can try the second part.
